# Symfony2 Assetic issue

Tags: symfony, assetic

i'm working on a `sf2 project` for last 3 months where i've been using assetic without problems. But now, when calling assetic on a new template i get de following error `Route "_assetic_baa4710.js" does not exist` which can be workaround by:

```
#config_dev.yml
assetic:
    use_controller: false
```

and removing the following assetic config from routing_dev.yml

```
#routing_dev.yml
#_assetic:
#    resource: .
#    type:     assetic
```

Does any one knows what's going on? Thx a lot! :D

Comment: I find that I often have to completey delete the cache directory when adding a new template containing a assetic manages stylesheet.  Never tracked down why.  I just live with it.

Comment: @Cerad I guess that's because AsseticBundle only searches for template files (in every registered bundle) when the cache is empty. That's why you need to clear `app/cache/<env>/assetic` to force a new lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I believe noisebleed's comment is the solution, it worked for me.

```
// app/config_dev.yml
assetic:
    use_controller: true
    bundles: ['FooBarBundle']
```

Comment: worked for me in production changing the config.yml to above.  After changing clear cache for --env=prod

Answer (score 0):

do a cache clear and problem should fix

php app/console cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

maybe is too late but... what worked for me:

```
php composer.phar install
php app/console cache:clear
php app/console cache:warmup
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a cache clean using

```
rm -rf apps/cache
```

[Assetic - Route "_assetic_001d5b7_0" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462673/assetic-route-assetic-001d5b7-0-does-not-exist)